# order by issue when using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have source table with query

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp) as Month_Name, COUNT(nc_deposit) as piece, 
    ISNULL(sum(nc_deposit),0) as amount,terminal_name
FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl
INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m 
    on cl.nc_log_id = m.nc_log_id
INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl 
    on m.sales_id = sl.sales_id 
INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h 
    on cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id
INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t 
    on h.terminal_id = t.terminal_id
INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c 
    on cl.cu_id = c.cu_id
WHERE YEAR(sales_timestamp)='2017' 
    and cl.currency_id = 2
    and c.card_type_id = '514'
GROUP BY terminal_name, DATENAME(MONTH,sales_timestamp), DATEPART(m,sales_timestamp)
ORDER BY DATEPART(m, sales_timestamp), terminal_nameerminal_name
```

and I wanted the data in pivot form. So I modified the query into this:

```
WITH source_table (
    terminal_name
    ,Month_Name
    ,piece
    ,amount
    )
AS (
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp) AS Month_Name
        ,COUNT(nc_deposit) AS piece
        ,ISNULL(sum(nc_deposit), 0) AS amount
        ,terminal_name
    FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl
    INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m ON cl.nc_log_id = m.nc_log_id
    INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl ON m.sales_id = sl.sales_id
    INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h ON cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id
    INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t ON h.terminal_id = t.terminal_id
    INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c ON cl.cu_id = c.cu_id
    WHERE YEAR(sales_timestamp) = '2017'
        AND cl.currency_id = 2
        AND c.card_type_id = '514'
    GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, sales_timestamp)
        ,terminal_name
        ,DATEPART(m, sales_timestamp)
    ORDER BY DATEPART(m, sales_timestamp)
        ,terminal_name
    )
SELECT pieces.terminal_name
    ,pieces.January AS JanPcs
    ,amounts.January AS JanAmt
    ,pieces.February AS FebPcs
    ,amounts.February AS FebAmt
    ,pieces.March AS MarPcs
    ,amounts.March AS MarAmt
    ,pieces.April AS AprilPcs
    ,amounts.April AS AprilAmt
    ,pieces.May AS MayPcs
    ,amounts.May AS MayAmt
    ,pieces.June AS JunePcs
    ,amounts.June AS JuneAmt
    ,pieces.July AS JulyPcs
    ,amounts.July AS JulyAmt
    ,pieces.August AS AugustPcs
    ,amounts.August AS AugustAmt
    ,pieces.September AS SeptPcs
    ,amounts.September AS SeptAmt
    ,pieces.October AS OctPcs
    ,amounts.October AS OctAmt
    ,pieces.November AS NovPcs
    ,amounts.November AS NovAmt
    ,pieces.December AS DecPcs
    ,amounts.December AS DecAmt
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT terminal_name
            ,Month_Name
            ,piece
        FROM source_table
        ) AS src_pieces
    PIVOT(MAX(piece) FOR Month_Name IN (
                January
                ,February
                ,March
                ,April
                ,May
                ,June
                ,July
                ,August
                ,September
                ,October
                ,November
                ,December
                )) AS pvt_pieces
    ) AS pieces
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT terminal_name
            ,Month_Name
            ,amount
        FROM source_table
        ) AS src_pieces
    PIVOT(MAX(amount) FOR Month_Name IN (
                January
                ,February
                ,March
                ,April
                ,May
                ,June
                ,July
                ,August
                ,September
                ,October
                ,November
                ,December
                )) AS pvt_pieces
    ) AS amounts ON (amounts.terminal_name = pieces.terminal_name)
```

The output should be like this:

```
  terminal_name    JanAmt   JanPcs .... DecAmt   DecPcs
 ------------------------------------------------------------
  terminal A       1000     100          2000     200
```

However, i got this error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

I tried many times to solve this but i didnt have any idea. Can you guys take a look on this? Thanks!

Comment: Remove `ORDER BY` clause from CTE query.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: The error is quite obvious. You can't use `ORDER BY` syntax inside CTE (Common Table Expressions). If you still need to sort the data, move it outside the query.

Comment: i cannot remove from the clause.. as i wanted the data is sorted by months correctly @maciej

Comment: the part that order by in the source table.. i cannot move it outside query as it gives me error @gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't conditional aggregation be simpler?

```
SELECT terminal_name
       sum(case when month(sales_timestamp) = 1 then nc_deposit else 0 end) as jan_amount,
       sum(case when month(sales_timestamp) = 2 then nc_deposit else 0 end) as feb_amount,
       . . .
       sum(case when month(sales_timestamp) = 12 then nc_deposit else 0 end) as dec_amount
FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl INNER JOIN
     dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m
     on cl.nc_log_id = m.nc_log_id INNER JOIN 
     dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl
     on m.sales_id = sl.sales_id INNER JOIN 
     dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h 
     on cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id INNER JOIN 
     dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t
     on h.terminal_id = t.terminal_id INNER JOIN 
     dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c
     on cl.cu_id = c.cu_id
WHERE YEAR(sales_timestamp) = 2017 AND
      cl.currency_id = 2 AND
      c.card_type_id = 514
GROUP BY terminal_name
ORDER BY terminal_name ;
```

This seems much simpler than a multi-part query, with CTEs, multiple subqueries and additional `JOIN`s.

Note that I removed the single quotes from `'2017'`.  The `YEAR()` function returns a number, so the comparison should be to a number.  Similarly, I assume that `card_type_id` is a number, not a string.

Comment: yes.. this applicable only to get the sum of nc_deposit.. how can i get the count for nc_deposit by months? as i wanted Jan Amt and Jan Pcs..@gordon

Answer (score 0):

A CTE cannot have an ORDER BY.

You can use:

WITH CTE AS:

Your Query

SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY...

Comment: sorry i am bit confuse. can you show me how? @SQL_M